# Regex Quantifier not working in string-match

Tags: regular-expressions, string

All the documentation I can find says this should be returning the index of the first of the three x's but instead it returns nil:

```
(string-match "x\{3\}" "string with 3 x's repeating: xxx")
```

[image]

update: I had to escape the backslashes:

```
(string-match "x\\{3\\}" "string with 3 x's repeating: xxx")
```

Comment: Need another backslash to escape.

Comment: Please write up the answer as an answer, and accept it. (It's fine to accept your own answer.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backslashes need to be escaped in strings:

`(string-match "x\\{3\\}" "string with 3 x's repeating: xxx")`